# GitExtensions Configuration error

Tags: visual-studio-2010, git, git-extensions

I installed GitExtensions for the main purpose of using GitHub with my visual studio 2010. When I start up GitExtensions, I get 2 errors in my checklist and also a startup error that says:
`Access to path 'c:\program files(x86)\GitExtensions\.gitconfig' is denied`.

There is no .gitconfig file in that directory. It wont allow me to setup the needed information such as my name and email. Is there anything I can do to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It shouldn't be looking for .gitconfig there.

It should be in `C:\users\username\.gitconfig` Make sure you have setting like below:

[image]

Comment: When I do this, it says git is not found then goes back to setting it to `c:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe`

Comment: Which one are you changing? You should change the one under `Environment` to use default for home.

Comment: I have it exactly as you have. default for HOME, and just git in the textbox at the top

Comment: Also in my user directory, I see no `.gitconofig` file

Comment: @Lol coder Haven't you clicked on Repair for `username and password` in the settings? Once you save that, it will be created

Comment: Oops meant email not password. Muscle memory I suppose, username followed by password.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably caused by a known bug in the latest version of Git Extensions. The bug is fixed already but the new version is not released yet. You can download the latest release candidate here:
http://code.google.com/p/gitextensions/downloads/detail?name=GitExtensions222SetupComplete.msi

You could also fix this by moving .gitconfig from c:\program files\gitextensions.gitconfig to c:\users\username.gitconfig manually. GitExtensions will detect the new location and will use it.